# Are there any NURBS Add-ons or future NURBS updates for Blender?

Tags: add-on, nurbs-surface

Is there any information about NURBS add-ons that can improve the functionality of NURBS within Blender? Are there any upcoming Blender updates planned to enhance NURBS capabilities?